# Is a product of congruence classes [2] and [3] [1]?(mod 5)

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $[k]=\{5n+k\ :\ n \in Z\}$, and define the product of two sets $X$ and $Y$ as $XY=\{xy\ :\ x \in X \text{ and }y \in Y\}$.
Then $[2][3]=[1]$?

Because $(5n+2)(5m+3)=5(5nm+2m+3n+1)+1$, $[2][3]=[1]$ when $5nm+2m+3n+1$ yields all integer by the proper choice of $n$ and $m$.
when $n=0, 5nm+2m+3n+1=2n+1$ so it covers all odd integers.
I'm working with remaining cases(even integers), but i don't see any solutions.

So question : Is any even integer can be written in a form $5nm+2m+3n+1$ for some integer $n,m$? so that $[2][3]=[1]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most evens can be written in this form, but there are exceptions. In particular, $2$ cannot. For any $m, n$, $5nm+2m+3n+1 \ne 2$

To see this, rewrite $5nm+2m+3n+1 = 2$ as $(2m - 1) + n(5m + 3) = 0$, which requires that $5m + 3$ divides $2m - 1$. But it is not true by inspection for $m = -1, 0, 1$, and for $|m| > 1$, we have $|5m + 3| > |2m - 1|$, so divisibility is impossible there as well.

This is why we do not define multiplication in $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$ by means of set multiplication on the cosets.

Comment: oh now I see this! by the way, how did you know that most even can be written in 5nm+2m+3n+1?

Comment: @benhwang - by testing. Note that if $a$ is representable, then so is $k(a -1) + 1$. Explore several values of $n$ and $m$, it wil be clear that a significant majority of even numbers should representable. But since the question was about what was not representable, I didn't explore any further than that.